# Pick up only fully written files in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, file-io, aix

I have a directory in aix which will receive files from a external application.
My java program should pick only those files which are completely written by the application.It should not pick the incomplete files which are being still written by the external application.
Can someone help with a sample?

Comment: Etiquette you must use operating system locks which are not portable across platforms or you must be able to separate written/not-written on the file name or location, or you must say that the time stamp must be X seconds old before you touch it.  For windows, if you can rename it, it isn't open.

Answer (score 1):

Try Apache Camel File Poller and stratergies OS or file renaiming to detect file access in progress

Comment: They don't guarantee this will work.

Answer (score 1):

One common way to solve this problem is to rename the file once it was completely written.

For example your application writes myFile.txt.tmp and once it is done it renames it to myFile.txt. Doing this you simply ignore the files ending in .tmp...

Or, as already said, by alexcpn have a look at the [Apache Camel File Component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)...

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to have the files written to a "temporary" directory first. After writing a file has finished, it should be moved to the final destination. Take care to have the "temporary" and the "final" directory on the same filesystem; otherwise, [`File.renameTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) might or might not work. When using Java 7, [`Files.move()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) might be of better use.

Obviously, your application only has to check for files in the "final" directory, since you know all files in that directory are completely written.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows there is no way to know when a file is locked for writing by another application, I've hit the same problem before. You can try using JNotify to listen for events and treat the exceptions that occur, as far as i know there is no other way, but in Unix checking if a file is locked should do the job `new File(fileName).canWrite()`